# Google Analytics API 3 giving me data from a different profile ID

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using the steps provided from [Use Google Analytics API to show information in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306872/use-google-analytics-api-to-show-information-in-c-sharp), and if I set a date to be yesterday, the data getting returned is from a web property that does not match that of the profile ID I am providing, but from a different property that's underneath my master account. If I set the date to be a week ago, it gives me the correct data from the specified profile ID.

How can this be happening? I created the app today in the Google API Console, using the same login I use for looking at multiple properties in Google Analytics. I made sure however to set the randomly-generated email address in the account's User Management admin.

Comment: There are to answers on that page the page with examples. The first one is to old, I wouldn't bother fixing it. If you are using that consider using the new version of the Google.Apis client lib.

The second one is for a service account which one are you using?

Comment: I am using the new Google Api, service account. And, using the code almost verbatim from the other stackoverflow question. I'm hoping to see somewhere on Google Analytics an announcement about the api not returning correct data and that they're fixing it, but no such luck.

Comment: Any chance you can post all of your code? Exactly what you are using.  If there is an issue I would like to know about it.  I haven't been able to recreate it.