# Getting reports from Google Analytics Reporting API v4 in C# .NET - GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I'm trying to follow the documentation for analytics reporting, but I'm getting pretty confused between the documentation for Oauth2 (which is in C# but I can't get to work), and the documentation for the analytics reporting API is very sparse (it has examples in Java and Python, but not C#). I've been reading over the following documentation:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

[Analytics Reporting API V4 Client Library for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850231/analytics-reporting-api-v4-client-library-for-net)

I've put together some code based on the Stack Overflow answer and the Google Developers [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) on Oauth2 for Asp.NET MVC. here is my code:

```
class GoogleAnalyticsUtil
{  
    public List<AnalyticsPage> GetReport(DateTime startDate)
    {
        List<AnalyticsPage> report = new List<AnalyticsPage>();
        try
        {
            var credentialTask = GetCredential();
            credentialTask.Wait();
            var credential = credentialTask.Result;
            using (var svc = new AnalyticsReportingService(
                new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Google Analytics API Console"
                }))
            {
                var dateRange = new DateRange
                {
                    StartDate = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                    EndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                };
                var sessions = new Metric
                {
                    Expression = "ga:sessions",
                    Alias = "Sessions"
                };
                var date = new Dimension { Name = "ga:date" };

                var reportRequest = new ReportRequest
                {
                    DateRanges = new List<DateRange> { dateRange },
                    Dimensions = new List<Dimension> { date },
                    Metrics = new List<Metric> { sessions },
                    ViewId = "<<view id>>"
                };
                var getReportsRequest = new GetReportsRequest
                {
                    ReportRequests = new List<ReportRequest> { reportRequest }
                };
                var batchRequest = svc.Reports.BatchGet(getReportsRequest);
                var response = batchRequest.Execute();
                foreach (var x in response.Reports.First().Data.Rows)
                {
                    report.Add(new AnalyticsPage()
                    {
                        Path = x.Dimensions.First(),
                        Views = x.Metrics.First().Values
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return report;
    }

    static async Task<UserCredential> GetCredential()
    {

        var clientSecretPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "client_secret.json";
        var credPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "credentials/GoogleAnalyticsApiConsole/";

        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretPath,
                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var secrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;            

            credential = await dsAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                secrets,
                new[] {AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.Analytics},
                "<<username>>", 
                CancellationToken.None, 
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true));

            return credential;
        }
    }
}

class AnalyticsPage
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Views { get; set; }
    public string ViewString { get; set; }
}

public class dsAuthorizationBroker : GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker
{
    public static string RedirectUri = "https://<<my website>>/AuthCallback/IndexAsync";

    public new static async Task<UserCredential> AuthorizeAsync(
        ClientSecrets clientSecrets,
        IEnumerable<string> scopes,
        string user,
        CancellationToken taskCancellationToken,
        IDataStore dataStore = null)
    {
        var initializer = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            ClientSecrets = clientSecrets,
        };
        return await AuthorizeAsyncCore(initializer, scopes, user,
            taskCancellationToken, dataStore).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private static async Task<UserCredential> AuthorizeAsyncCore(
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer initializer,
        IEnumerable<string> scopes,
        string user,
        CancellationToken taskCancellationToken,
        IDataStore dataStore)
    {
        initializer.Scopes = scopes;
        initializer.DataStore = dataStore ?? new FileDataStore(Folder);
        var flow = new dsAuthorizationCodeFlow(initializer);
        return await new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow,
            new LocalServerCodeReceiver())
            .AuthorizeAsync(user, taskCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}


public class dsAuthorizationCodeFlow : GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
{
    public dsAuthorizationCodeFlow(Initializer initializer)
        : base(initializer) { }

    public override AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl
                    CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(string redirectUri)
    {
        return base.CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(dsAuthorizationBroker.RedirectUri);
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace MySite.Web.Controllers.WebAPI
{
    public class AuthCallbackController : Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.Controllers.AuthCallbackController
    {
        protected override Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.FlowMetadata FlowData
        {
            get { return new AppFlowMetadata(); }
        }

        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
        public async Task IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
                AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (result.Credential != null)
            {
                var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                    ApplicationName = "PMA"
                });

                // YOUR CODE SHOULD BE HERE..
                // SAMPLE CODE:
                //var list = await service.Files.List().ExecuteAsync();
            }

            Response.Redirect(result.RedirectUri);
        }
    }
}
```

The authorization in `GetCredential()` is failing, with the error

`Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=224691372209-3ljoils93ufa13mgk2ahilvniqa30f2p.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2FAuthCallback%2FIndexAsync&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics" for authorization. See inner exception for details.

When I try to go directly to mysite.com/AuthCallback/IndexAsync, I get a 404, so maybe that's the problem? But I'm not sure what's wrong with the controller, or why that's causing the authorization to fail. I'm using a Web Application Auth2.0 client ID, but I also tried using type 'Other' which doesn't take RedirectUrls in the parameters, but that didn't work either. Can I get it to authorize without redirecting anywhere? I need `credential.result` from the authorization to continue with the rest of my code, or is there another way in C# that I should be getting data from the Google Analytics Reporting API?

Comment: Just want to confirm if you've seen [Google Analytics Reporting API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/analyticsreporting/v4)?

Comment: Have you enabled the API for your project? Perhaps if you included the inner exception, it might have more details.